# How to display #REF! (You need to connect these sheets) when using IFERROR to display Blank Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I understand that Google Sheets must be explicitly granted permission to pull data from other spreadsheets using IMPORTRANGE

However, when using `IFERROR` alongside `VLOOKUP` to display the value argument has a blank cell - How do you still allow for the #REF! (You need to connect these sheets) to be displayed?

I appreciate that as a workaround I could just display a `"."` but I'm curious if it's possible to legitimately without a workaround display a blank cell with no valid result but still allow for #REF! (You need to connect these sheets) to be displayed?

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Meta!$A$12,IMPORTRANGE(""&$M31&"","Template!$A$1:$H$6"),7, false), "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would decrease performance, probably by a lot, but I think this (or something similar) would technically work:

```
=if(1+0*importrange(...),iferror(vlookup(...)))
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, they need to be connected and IFERROR will only hide that #REF! error. if you got complex (non-standalone IMPORTRANGE formula) that <kbd>Allow access</kbd> button will not appear. you are always obligated to run the IMPORTRANGE fx as standalone to establish the connection (it can be just a single cell - `=IMPORTRANGE(""&$M31&"","Template!$A$1")`) and only then use your complex (multi-layer) formula.